# Obstrusive window on syntastic from vim for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, vim-plugin, syntastic

Syntastic is raising an error each ":w" refered to Python3 class defintion. I also tryed to disabled messages window without sucess using

```
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 0
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

The class definition raising the error is something like

```
class SomeClass(metaclass=PoolMeta):
    pass
```

The question is how coudl I disable that window in order to prevent raising that wrong alerts?

Image attached

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to set syntastic_auto_loc_list to 0 or 2.

> **syntastic_auto_loc_list**
>
> Type: integer
>
> Default: 2
>
> Use this option to tell syntastic to automatically open and/or close the
> location-list (see syntastic-error-window).
>
> **When set to 0 the error window will be neither opened nor closed
> automatically.**
>
> **let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0**
>
> When set to 1 the error window will be automatically opened when errors are detected, and closed when none are detected.
>
> let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
>
> **When set to 2 the error window will be automatically closed when no errors are detected, but not opened automatically.**
>
> **let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 2**
>
> When set to 3 the error window will be automatically opened when errors are detected, but not closed automatically.
>
> let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 3